# SQL query that searches comma-delimited field

Tags: mysql, sql, split

I have a student table which looks something like this:

```
 id  |  name  |  school_descriptors
-------------------------------------------------------
 1   |  Rob   |  Comp Sci,Undergraduate,2020  
 2   |  Tim   |  Business,MBA,2022
 3   |  Matt  |  Business,MBA,2022
 4   |  Jack  |  Law,Masters,2024
 5   |  Steph |  Comp Sci,Masters,2022
```

The school_descriptors field is just one column, and stores information about the Course, Qualification and Graduation year as a comma-delimited string. (it's terribly designed and I wish it could be split up into its own fields, but it can't right now (I am not the database owner))

I want to provide an interface where teachers can quickly find students that match certain Course, Qualifications and Graduation years, and thus would like to create relevant queries.

**Question 1:** For example, I would like a teacher to be able to select from the UI: "Business", "MBA" and get returned students with ID 2 and 3. Specifically, an example question I have is: *Find students who are in the Business Course and doing the MBA qualification:*

```
SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE school_descriptors LIKE '%Business%' AND school_descriptors LIKE '%MBA%'
```

The query I have in mind is a basic LIKE query, but I can't help but think there is a more efficient query that can take advantage of the fact that the school_descriptor string is 1) always in a specific order (e.g. course, qualification, graduation), and 2) comma-delimited, and thus could be perhaps split. The table currently sits at ~5000 rows so relatively small but is expected to grow.

**Related question 2**: *Find students who are in the Comp Sci Course and graduating after 2019:*

Would it be possible to split the school_descriptors field and add a `>2019` operand?

Many thanks!

Comment: "*I wish it could be split up into its own fields, but it can't right now :)*" Why not? This seems to be a pretty arbitrary requirement. This problem would be at least an order of magnitude easier to deal with if you did take the time to properly normalize this table.

Comment: See also [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: @Luuk the question's tag is MySql, not SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, unfortunately I am not the database owner and am creating the UI for a school who is a client which is why I am unable to change the table config.

Comment: Function FIND_IN_SET searches string literal in CSV list (strict quiality).

Comment: "unfortunately I am not the database owner"  Please find the database owner and tell to change it.  Otherwise you will be the one who lives with nightmare.

Comment: Really appreciate all the feedback! After reading all your comments, my priority now is to get the database normalized, while using one of the substring_index queries as a very interim solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql you can use the function [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to split the column `school_descriptors`.
This will work only if the positions of Course, Qualification and Graduation year are fixed.

```
select *,
  substring_index(school_descriptors, ',', 1) Course, 
  substring_index(substring_index(school_descriptors, ',', 2), ',', -1) Qualification, 
  substring_index(school_descriptors, ',', -1) Graduation
from student_table
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7).
Results:

```
> id | name  | school_descriptors          | Course   | Qualification | Graduation
> -: | :---- | :-------------------------- | :------- | :------------ | :---------
>  1 | Rob   | Comp Sci,Undergraduate,2020 | Comp Sci | Undergraduate | 2020      
>  2 | Tim   | Business,MBA,2022           | Business | MBA           | 2022      
>  3 | Matt  | Business,MBA,2022           | Business | MBA           | 2022      
>  4 | Jack  | Law,Masters,2024            | Law      | Masters       | 2024      
>  5 | Steph | Comp Sci,Masters,2022       | Comp Sci | Masters       | 2022
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, name, 
  substring_index(school_descriptors,',',1) as course, 
  substring_index(substring(school_descriptors,length(substring_index(school_descriptors,',',1))+2,200),',',1) as Qualifications, 
  substring_index(school_descriptors,',',-1) as year
from student;
```

output:

```
+------+-------+----------+----------------+------+
| id   | name  | course   | Qualifications | year |
+------+-------+----------+----------------+------+
|    1 | Rob   | Comp Sci | Undergraduate  | 2020 |
|    2 | Tim   | Business | MBA            | 2022 |
|    3 | Matt  | Business | MBA            | 2022 |
|    4 | Jack  | Law      | Masters        | 2024 |
|    5 | Steph | Comp Sci | Masters        | 2022 |
+------+-------+----------+----------------+------+
```

A link to the docs, in case you want to know about [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1:**

```
SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE school_descriptors REGEXP ['Business','MBA']
```

By using this query you can get all the records that are having Business OR MBA.
If you want to select only **Business, MBA** you can try like this

SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE school_descriptors LIKE '%Business,MBA%'

**Answer 2:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM student 
WHERE
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(school_descriptors , ',', 1), ',', -1)='Comp Sci' 
  AND
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(school_descriptors , ',', 3), ',', -1)> 2019;
```

Answer (score 0):

LIKE operator is not the best choice. In some cases, the LIKE operator fails us. Example if you have a Master Business in School descriptors column LIKE operator will pull that record also. To find the exact match you need to use RLIKE

```
SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE school_descriptors RLIKE '[[:<:]]'Business'[[:>:]]' AND school_descriptors RLIKE '[[:<:]]'MBA'[[:>:]]'
```